# Foxpro combobox get selected value?

Tags: combobox, visual-foxpro, selectedvalue

How to get selected value (two fields binding: name (0) and id(1)), selected index of combobox in foxpro  9.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thisform.yourCombobox.Value

The "Value" propert will be based on whatever the "BoundColumn" is of the combobox.

```
So, if for example your RowSource is "alias.ColumnX,ColumnM"
and the RowSourceType is "6=Fields" from a table
and the BoundColumn is 2 (meaning the second column in the list)
```

then the "Value" will be that of the "ColumnM" as either numeric, character or whatever the column represents.

```
If the "BoundColumn" property was 1, 
the "Value" would have the value from "ColumnX" from the table
```